# Calling method object.getId() using reflection from hibernate persistent throwing lazyInitializeException

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection

I´m trying to make a generic loader to hibernate, heres the problem.
My view searches for an array of objects and get it from controller, the controller closes the session.
Then, the view needs to use the object(s) information and some relationships. Since I am using Lazy Load, Im trying to make a method that load the object and the objects that are in the relationship passed by the method, the thing is that when I find the object im searching for, I call getId from this object in order to make the object to load. But the getId blocks and never returns.

The usage of the method is:

LoadGeneric.load(myObject, Class1.class, Class2.class ...);
And all relationships that myObejct have with Class1 and Class2 would have the objects loaded, also the Class1, would have Class2 loaded if they hae a relationship and so on...

Here is my code so far:

```
public class LoadGeneric 
{
    private static ArrayList<Object> objs = new ArrayList<Object>();


    public static void load(Object objeto, Class... loadClasses) throws Exception
    {
        Session s = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        try
        {
            if(objeto instanceof Collection)
            {
                Collection lo = (Collection) objeto;
                for(Object ob : lo)
                {
                    Method mGetId = findGetIdMethod(ob);
                    Object mid = mGetId.invoke(ob, (Object[]) null);
                    Integer id = (Integer) mid; 
                    s.get(ob.getClass(), id);
                    LoadGeneric.invokeAllMethods(ob, loadClasses);     
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Method mGetId = findGetIdMethod(objeto);
                Object mid = mGetId.invoke(objeto, (Object[]) null);
                Integer id = (Integer) mid;
                s.get(objeto.getClass(), id);
                LoadGeneric.invokeAllMethods(objeto, loadClasses);           
            }
        }
        finally
        {
           objs.clear();
           if(s.isOpen())
               s.close();
        }
    }

    //Find method like getIdNameOfTheClass
    private static Method findGetIdMethod(Object object) throws Exception
    {
        Class co = object.getClass();
        Method[] ml = co.getDeclaredMethods();
        String[] name = co.getName().split("\\.");
        String mn = "getid"+name[name.length-1];
        mn = mn.toLowerCase();
        for(Method m : ml)
        {
            if(m.getName().toLowerCase().contains(  mn  ))
                return m;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Erro ao achar método 'get id' do objeto, procurado algo como: "+mn);
    }

    //Find all methods that returns the class searched
    private static List<Method> findGetObjectMethods(Object object, 
            Class searchedClass) throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<Method> lm = new ArrayList<Method>();
        Class co = object.getClass();
        Method[] ml = co.getDeclaredMethods();
        for(Method m : ml)
        {
            if(m.getReturnType().equals(searchedClass))
                lm.add(m);
            else if(m.getReturnType().equals(java.util.Collection.class))
            {
                System.out.println("****************************COLLECTION: "+m);
            }
            else
            {
                //System.out.println("TIPO DE RETORNO DESCARTADO: "+m);
            }
        }
        return lm;
    }


    private static void invokeAllMethods(Object object, Class... classes) throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<Method> lm = new ArrayList<Method>();

        for(Class c : classes)
        {
            lm.addAll(findGetObjectMethods(object, c));
        }

        for(Method m : lm)
        {
            System.out.println("Invocando metodo: "+m);
            Object o = m.invoke(object, (Object[]) null);
            if(o != null)
            {
                findGetIdMethod(o).invoke(o, (Object[]) null);
                objs.add(o);
                if(objs.contains(o))
                    continue;
                invokeAllMethods(o, classes);
            }
        }
    }



}
```

PS: All my method´s classes that return X class have a name like getIdNameOfXClass()

EDIT: Changed to new code.... Im getting exceptions that my get id method cannot find getIdNameOfClass_*$$*_javassist.......I think is hibernate giving me a proxy instead of a real object, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved problem with another stackoverflow post
all I did was unproxying the entity

```
SessionImpl imp = (SessionImpl) session;
o = imp.getPersistenceContext().unproxyAndReassociate(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your `findGetIdMethod` is throwing an `UnknownObjectException`.  In your code you are looking for a method name that is not `getId()` but is instead effectively:

```
"getid" + class.getSimpleName()
```

Is that really what you want?  `UnknownObjectException` is a RMI exception which is a bit strange to throw there but it extends `Exception` so must have been caught by someone.  Are you catching exceptions appropriately and logging them?  It looks like your `load()` method will throw that.

I would rewrite that method to do something like:

```
co.getMethod("getId");
```

But then again maybe the name of the `getId()` method is something like `getIdClassName()` for some reason.

Comment: im sorry that code is wrong, and i shouldnt be throwing an UnknownObjectException, I fixed that part. But the problem is that hibernate is giving me proxies instead of objects and I get a message like, cannot find method getIdNameOfClass__$$__javassist....